# I have setup my own ca root certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, ca

I have setup my own car root certificate. Now I want to know that how can I get my root certificate into different OS's trusted ca root store and how to sell certificates from my website from that can root certificate.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The [Chromium website](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy) has a good collection of links for getting your certificate included into various operating systems. The [Mozilla guide](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/policy/) is probably be the best place to start.

Heads-up: This is going to take several years, and involve setting up a corporation with regular audits. And then waiting for everyone to upgrade their browsers and operating systems to a version that includes your certificate. There’s a small chance you can do this for under ~USD$100,000, not counting your own time.

Search Bugzilla for examples. For example, it took Deutsche Telekom [over two years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=378882#c142) to get their CA into Firefox, despite being a huge corporation that presumably had all the paperwork ready in advance. On the other hand, the Korea Information Security Agency has been [waiting eight years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=335197) to get their CA into Firefox, despite already being in Internet Explorer.